# Eclipse no reconoce notación JAXB

Tags: java, jaxb

Necesito construir un XML partiendo de un archivo de texto para lo que he creado una clase POJO para guardar la información, al momento de asignar los vínculos de la clase con el XML no hay forma que me reconozca ninguna notación de JAXB, tampoco me da opción de importación... he visto que muchos trabajan con Netbeans y no se si será porque lo trae de forma nativa. Alguien sabe decirme si debo instalar alguna api o algo para que funcione en Eclipse o como hacer?
Gracias

Answer (score 1):

Puede ser una de estas cosas:

- necesitas [configurar](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52947423/236345) el *running environment* para que apunte a un JDK y no a un JRE.
- [Instalar](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34492834/236345) el plugin Web Tools Platform.
- [Usar la versión](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6952551/236345) de Eclipse para Java EE. Trae todos los plugins y configuraciones que necesitas para ésto. El instalador es el mismo pero en la configuración le dices para qué lo vas a usar.